# Joi Validation with two empty arrays

Tags: node.js, testing, joi

I am trying to use the Joi Library to prevent two arrays to be empty or null. Either of them can be null or empty but both cannot. In my research I found ways to prevent two empty strings but not arrays. I tried a couple of variations of using when but have not found a simple solution. In each case I end up in a circular dependency. The dependency issue makes sense but I am not sure how to make the library work for this case. Here is an example of my latest attempt to make this work.

```
Joi.object({
    addUsers: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().email()),
    removeUsers: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().email())
}).keys({
    addUsers: Joi.array().min(0).when(Joi.ref('removeUsers').length(), {
        is: 0,
        then: Joi.array().min(1)
    }),
    removeUsers: Joi.array().min(0).when(Joi.ref('addUsers').length(), {
        is: 0,
        then: Joi.array().min(1)
    })
}).xor('addUsers', 'removeUsers')
            .message('Both or Either addUsers or removeUsers must have an array of email addresses. Both cannot be empty')
```

This creates the following circular dependency error

"item added into group removeUsers created a dependencies error","stack":"Error: item added into group removeUsers created a dependencies error"

Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and experimentation, I was able to get it to work with the following solution

```js
Joi.object({ 
            addUsers: Joi.when('removeUsers', {
                is: Joi.array().length(0),
                then: Joi.array()
                    .items(Joi.string().email())
                    .unique()
                    .required()
                    .min(1)
                    .messages({
                        'array.unique':
                            'addUsers or removeUsers must contain a unique list of emails',
                        'array.min':
                            'addUsers or removeUsers must contain at least 1 email',
                        'any.required':
                            'addUsers or removeUsers must contain at least 1 email'
                    })
                    .example(['some.user@email.com', 'non.user@email.com']),
                otherwise: Joi.array()
                    .items(
                        Joi.string()
                            .email()
                            .custom((value, helper) => {

                                const testArray = helper.state.ancestors[1].removeUsers; // Joi.in('removeUsers').path;
                                if (testArray) {
                                    const test = testArray.includes(value);

                                    if (test) {
                                        throw new Error(
                                            'addUsers or removeUsers must not contain the same email'
                                        );
                                    }
                                }
                                return value;
                            })
                    )
                    .unique()
                    .messages({
                        'array.min':
                            'addUsers or removeUsers must contain at least 1 email',
                        'any.valid':
                            'addUsers or removeUsers must not contain the same email'
                    })
                    .example(['some.user@email.com', 'non.user@email.com'])
            }),
            removeUsers: Joi.array()
                .items(Joi.string().email())
                .unique()
                .messages({
                    'array.unique':
                        'addUsers or removeUsers must contain a unique list of emails'
                })
                .example(['some.other.user@email.com'])
})
```